# Access React context outside of component

Tags: reactjs, localization, next.js, contentful

I'm using React context to store the locale for a NextJS website (e.g. example.com/en/). The setup looks like this:

**components/Locale/index.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';

const Context = React.createContext();
const { Consumer } = Context;

const Provider = ({ children, locale }) => (
  <Context.Provider value={{ locale }}>
    {children}
  </Context.Provider>
);

export default { Consumer, Provider };
```

**pages/_app.jsx**

```
import App, { Container } from 'next/app';
import React from 'react';

import Locale from '../components/Locale';


class MyApp extends App {
  static async getInitialProps({ Component, ctx }) {
    const pageProps = Component.getInitialProps ? await Component.getInitialProps(ctx) : {};
    const locale = ctx.asPath.split('/')[1];
    return { pageProps, locale };
  }

  render() {
    const {
      Component,
      locale,
      pageProps,
    } = this.props;

    return {
      <Container>
        <Locale.Provider locale={locale}>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </Locale.Provider>
      </Container>
    };
  }
}
```

So far so good. Now within one of my pages, I get data from Contentful CMS API in the `getInitialProps` lifecycle method. That looks a bit like this:

**pages/index.jsx**

```
import { getEntries } from '../lib/data/contentful';

const getInitialProps = async () => {
  const { items } = await getEntries({ content_type: 'xxxxxxxx' });
  return { page: items[0] };
};
```

At this stage I need to make this query with the locale so I need to access `Local.Consumer` in the above `getInitialProps`. Is this possible?

Comment: May I ask, how you solved this in the end? I am facing a very similar challenge.

Answer (score 2):

This does not appear to be possible according to the documentation here: https://github.com/zeit/next.js/#fetching-data-and-component-lifecycle
You access React context data by wrapping your component in the context's Consumer like this:

```
<Locale.Consumer>
  ({locale}) => <Index locale={locale} />
</Locale.Consumer>
```

But getInitialProps is run for top-level pages and does not have access to the props.

Can you get your entries in another React lifecycle method, like [componentDidMount?](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)
Then you could store your items in the component state.